# node dist/server.js exits without error messages

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal app.

I am able to run 'npm run start', which executes 'ng serve' and the live development server starts listening.

If instead I run 'node dist/server.js', it simply exits without any info or error messages.

Comment: Hi did you get any solution for this..???

Answer (score 0):

check out the `$.scripts.start` field within the project's `package.json` file. That will tell you what command is being invoked through `npm start`, which might not necessarily be `node dist/server.js`. Default values for the `start` script are found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#default-values)

Also, depending on what flavor of Javascript they are running, there might be a build step that you are missing.

Comment: Sorry I meant 'npm run start' which runs 'ng serve'. I have updated my post.